# python tkinter moving circle with cursor

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to create agar.io game in tkinter. Im trying to move a circle with my cursor but i get this error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1541, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 592, in callit
func(*args)
File "/Users/Hari/Desktop/Agario.py", line 32, in move1
g1, g2 = cursor()
TypeError: cursor() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

This is my code. This is not complete i just want to get the key bind for moving my cursor finished and then i will go about moving the circle itself

```
import Tkinter
from random import randint
tk=Tkinter.Tk() 
canvas=Tkinter.Canvas(width=1250, height=700)
canvas.configure(background='red')
frame=canvas.create_rectangle(10,10,1240,690, fill="white")
om=canvas.create_oval(50,50,75,75, fill="blue")
lis=[]
count=0
on=0 
def move1():
    global lis, count, on
    count=count+1
    if(count%100==0):
        c1=randint(10,1235)
        c2=randint(10,685)
        o=canvas.create_oval(c1,c2,c1+5,c2+5, fill="green")
        lis1=[]
        lis1.append(c1)
        lis1.append(c2)
        lis1.append(c1+5)
        lis1.append(c2+5)
        lis.append(lis1)
    g1, g2 = cursor()
    print g1, g2
    x1, y1, x2, y2=canvas.coords(om)

    canvas.after(1,move1)
move1()
def cursor(event):
    m1=event.x
    m2=event.y
    return m1, m2
tk.bind("<B1-Motion>", cursor)
canvas.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: The error message looks pretty self-explanatory. Your cursor method requires an argument, but you're calling it without an argument.

Comment: You are calling the callback-function `cursor` from within `move`, but instead you probably want to call `move` from within `cursor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should understand this error message literally.
"cursor() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)" message means
that the cursor function was defined as accepting event as argument `def cursor(event):`
but then you call it without any argument `g1, g2 = cursor()`